# Complete subspace of connected space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness, complete-spaces

Let $A$ be a connected metric space and $B$ subspace such that $B$ and $A\backslash B$ are complete.

> How do I show that $B$ is either empty or equal to $A$?

What I thought:
We need to show that $B$ not empty implies $B=A$.
$B$ is complete, so each Cauchy sequence converges in $B$. Further $A$ has exactly two clopens, namely $A$ and empty.
I think that we need to show that $B$ is clopen. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B$ is complete then $B$ has to be closed. But that is true for $A\setminus B$ too. So $B$ and $A\setminus B$ are clopen.

Comment: Proof of closedness: suppose $A$ is complete in a metric space $X$, and let $p \in \overline{A}$. Then there is a sequence $(a_n)$, all in $A$, such that $a_n \to p$ in $X$. This sequence is Cauchy (in $A$) (easy to check, use the triangle inequality via $p$), so converges *in $A$*, and so, as limits of sequences are unique, $p \in A$, so $A$ is closed.